Spring Boot 3 micrometer tracing in MDC
I need to organize custom tracing and logging.
Logging logback (Slf4j).
I have a service that needs to read fields from the header and add them to the correlation (before switching to spring boot 3, I used MDC to distribute data). Plus I also added custom fields to MDC for logging.
After switching to spring boot 3 (from sleuth to micrometer), I don’t understand how I can manage data in MDC.
Can you tell me how to correctly add custom fields to the correlation?
How to fill out Mdc when using a micrometer.
How to transfer everything from the parent thread to a new one, and clean it up after completion?
Here's my example:

Set up a logging pattern:

logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%clr(%d){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%X{testRemoteBaggage}-%X{testLocalBaggage}]){magenta} %clr([%40.40t]){faint} %clr(${LOG_CORRELATION_PATTERN:-}){faint}%clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wEx"


Configured adding custom fields to the correlation (the first field should be sent with requests, the second should not):

management:
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1.0
    baggage:
      correlation:
        fields: testRemoteBaggage, testLocalBaggage
      remote-fields: testRemoteBaggage
      local-fields: testLocalBaggage


Configured a task executor to work asynchronously with virtual threads:

spring:
  threads:
    virtual:
      enabled: true

@EnableAsync
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class DummyJsonTracingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AsyncTaskExecutor applicationTaskExecutor() {
        return new TaskExecutorAdapter(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public TomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizer<?> protocolHandlerVirtualThreadExecutorCustomizer() {
        return protocolHandler -> {
            protocolHandler.setExecutor(Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor());
        };
    }
}


Added a filter that adds custom fields to the correlation:

@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AddBaggageFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter implements OrderedFilter {
    private static final String fieldRemote = "testRemoteBaggage";
    private static final String fieldLocal = "testLocalBaggage";

    private final Tracer tracer;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String baggagefieldRemote = request.getHeader(fieldRemote);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(baggagefieldRemote)) {
            baggagefieldRemote = "autoValue"+fieldRemote;
        }
        String baggagefieldLocal = request.getHeader(fieldLocal);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(baggagefieldLocal)) {
            baggagefieldLocal = "autoValue"+fieldLocal;
        }
        log.warn("baggagefieldRemote value : [{}]", baggagefieldRemote);
        log.warn("baggagefieldLocal value : [{}]", baggagefieldLocal);

        try (BaggageInScope baggageRemote = tracer.createBaggageInScope(fieldRemote, baggagefieldRemote);
             BaggageInScope baggageLocal = tracer.createBaggageInScope(fieldLocal, baggagefieldLocal)) {
            log.warn("baggagefieldRemote was created!");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 2;
    }
}

But in the logs I see that the correlation is displayed only for the main thread.
2024-07-14 14:05:28,274  WARN 23716 --- [test1-] [                        tomcat-handler-1] [6693bf08c4ecb0e29507c9dbc43570fe-9507c9dbc43570fe] b.g.t.rest.AddBaggageFilter              : baggagefieldRemote value : [test1]
2024-07-14 14:05:28,275  WARN 23716 --- [test1-] [                        tomcat-handler-1] [6693bf08c4ecb0e29507c9dbc43570fe-9507c9dbc43570fe] b.g.t.rest.AddBaggageFilter              : baggagefieldLocal value : [autoValuetestLocalBaggage]
2024-07-14 14:05:28,276  WARN 23716 --- [test1-autoValuetestLocalBaggage] [                        tomcat-handler-1] [6693bf08c4ecb0e29507c9dbc43570fe-9507c9dbc43570fe] b.g.t.rest.AddBaggageFilter              : baggagefieldRemote was created!
2024-07-14 14:05:28,279 DEBUG 23716 --- [test1-autoValuetestLocalBaggage] [                        tomcat-handler-1] [6693bf08c4ecb0e29507c9dbc43570fe-9507c9dbc43570fe] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/categoryInfo", parameters={}
2024-07-14 14:05:28,285 DEBUG 23716 --- [test1-autoValuetestLocalBaggage] [                        tomcat-handler-1] [6693bf08c4ecb0e29507c9dbc43570fe-9507c9dbc43570fe] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to by.gvu.testtracingrestclient.controller.SimpleController#getListProducts()
2024-07-14 14:05:29,128 DEBUG 23716 --- [test1-autoValuetestLocalBaggage] [                        tomcat-handler-1] [6693bf08c4ecb0e29507c9dbc43570fe-9507c9dbc43570fe] o.s.web.client.DefaultRestClient         : Reading to [java.util.List<java.lang.String>]
2024-07-14 14:05:29,377 DEBUG 23716 --- [-] [        ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9] [                                                 ] o.s.web.client.DefaultRestClient         : Reading to [java.util.List<by.gvu.testtracingrestclient.model.Product>]
2024-07-14 14:05:29,689 DEBUG 23716 --- [-] [       ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-10] [                                                 ] o.s.web.client.DefaultRestClient         : Reading to [java.util.List<by.gvu.testtracingrestclient.model.Product>]
2024-07-14 14:05:29,734 DEBUG 23716 --- [-] [        ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4] [                                                 ] o.s.web.client.DefaultRestClient         : Reading to [java.util.List<by.gvu.testtracingrestclient.model.Product>]
2024-07-14 14:05:29,734 DEBUG 23716 --- [-] [       ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-12] [                                                 ] o.s.web.client.DefaultRestClient         : Reading to [java.util.List<by.gvu.testtracingrestclient.model.Product>]

UPDATED
The problem was not related to virtual threads.

Does this work as you expect when you don't use virtual threads: spring.threads.virtua.enabled is false and Spring Async and Tomcat Protocol Handler are not configured with virtual threads? If it does, could you post the log?

@igor.zh I checked the application without virtual threads, the application also does not work as I expect. I created an example on GitHub to show it clearly : Example project

OK, so the issue is VT-unrelated; might make sense to update question's title correspondingly. The MRE you posted is an excellent move! I'll try to look at it.  In the meantime, have you checked this thread? A micrometer test project, I created yesterday from your description does set your testRemoteBaggage and testRemoteBaggage variables to MDC context, but from what I understand you are looking for correlation records in the log.

@igor.zh Thanks for the reminder, I updated the title of the question and removed the tag.
As for the example branch, I have a problem not only that I can’t find traceId and spanId in the logs. Logs that do not contain these values ​​are generated by an asynchronous RestClient, which makes a request to another service in a new thread. And as a result, the correlation is not passed to the called service.
I'm trying to find a way to distribute the MDC context to the generated threads, so that at the same time the correlation is transferred to the rest of the calls.

Thanks for editing! Let me clarify what is your issue: when you say  "generated by an asynchronous RestClient" do you mean by that line 32 of Client's DummyJsonTracingService : parallelStream? When you invoke Server at line 26 the testRemoteBaggage header is passed correctly to Server, right? I am currently able to see only one issue: when Client invokes Server on in parallel, the header is not passed to the latter. Is this your issue or there is something else I missed? By "generated threads" in your last comment do you mean the threads, generated by parallelStream?

In the DummyJsonTracingService.java class, line 24-27 makes the rest call from the main thread. This call is made by passing the testRemoteBaggage field to the header.
But in the DummyJsonTracingService.java class on line 30 parallelStream is opened. This parallelStream in the new threads makes the rest calls on lines 33-37. These calls are made from threads in which the following values ​​are not filled in the MDC: traceId , spanId and testRemoteBaggage. These values ​​do not go into the log and are also not transmitted to the header of rest calls.

OK, now I see the problem. Looks like Observation engine, not only MDC, stores some stuff into ThreadLocal, and parallelStream/ForkJoinPool-spawned threads, of course, don't have an access to the ThreadLocal of "main" (Tomcat worker) thread. Just give me some time, hopefully it won't be too difficult to transfer relevant values from "main" ThreadLocal to  FTJ thread one. Curious, however, how it worked with Sleuth you worked previously with you said...

I think I have a solution. The problem, as it seems to me, is that ObservationRegistry keeps current Observation.Scope in its ThreadLocal, and with "non-main", like you said, threads we need to set the current scope. On "main"/Tomcat worker thread this job is done by ServerHttpObservationFilter , configured by Spring Boot; on "non-mains" we have to do it "manually". Wouldn't you want to update your question to include the usage of  parallelStream, which, as we agreed, was a main culprit? Otherwise, I'll be answering one of your comments, not your question.

As it follows from the MRE the OP posted the problem is with execution of RestClient-powered requests on separate threads, in the OP case threads, managed by parallelStream/ForkJoinPool.
List<String> categories = ...

categories.parallelStream().map(category -> {
    List<Product> productList = restClient.post()
                        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("...").build(category))
                        .retrieve()
...

RestClient does integrate with Micrometer Observation: upon execution of a request it starts an Observation and that one retrieves parent Observation form ObservationRegistry. ObservationRegistry, in turn, stores current Observation (Observation.Scope) in its ThreadLocal. When RestClient is executed on a container (Tomcat) thread, ServerHttpObservationFilter , configured by Spring Boot, takes care of setting current Observation to the registry, but when a thread, managed by parallelStream/ForkJoinPool, is about to execute RestClient, this thread does not have an access to ThreadLocal of Tomcat thread, and therefore, to initial (parent) Observation.
This is a well-known Context Propagation problem.
Micrometer framework anticipated this kind of issues and provisioned special library for it: Context Propagation, its purpose is to

...assists with context propagation across different types of context mechanisms, such as ThreadLocal ...

This library provides a special kind of ExecutorService, ContextExecutorService, which allows to

propagate context to the task when it is executed.

ContextExecutorService wraps other Executor in its static wrap method, let's use as delegatee same ForkJoinPool as used in parellelStream:
@Configuration
public class PropagationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ExecutorService propagationExecutorService() {
        return ContextExecutorService.wrap(Executors.newWorkStealingPool(), 
            (Supplier<ContextSnapshot>) () -> ContextSnapshotFactory.builder().build().captureAll());
    }
}

Then the instance of this ExecutorService could be injected into a class that issues the requests, for example, a Service:
@Autowired
private ExecutorService contextExecutorService;

and then use this ExecutorService to submit requests in parallel.
Let's now apply this approach to the OP's snippet, staying in the same streams paradigm:
    List<String> categories = ...

    return categories.stream().map( (category) -> {
            return contextExecutorService.submit( () -> {
                return new CategoryDetails(category, restClient.post()
                        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("...").build(category))
                        .retrieve()
                        .body(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Product>>() {}), null);
            });
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .stream()
        .map( (future) -> {
            try {
                return future.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

Note that first collect and subsequent stream() are necessary to allow parallel execution of CategoryDetails retrieval.
Obviously, this is less elegant than parellelStream approach; it seems, however, that there is no reliable way to use custom Executor for parellelStreams.
This approach, however, correctly propagates Observation Context to ExecutorService-managed threads and further to the server that handles the requests. It might also be preferable to parellelStreams because according to Parallel streams in Java: Benchmarking and performance considerations blog they

might not provide significant benefits for the I/O operations

It still might be possible to use the OP's original parallelStream approach, but this solution, which involves "manual" propagation of Observation Scope to the parallelStream-controlled threads via MDC Context, is not recommended as less scalable and MDC-coupled:
@Autowired
private ObservationRegistry registry;

... 

final Scope currentScope = registry.getCurrentObservationScope();
final Map<String, String> mdcContext = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();   
categories.parallelStream().map(category -> {
    final Scope oldScope = observationRegistry.getCurrentObservationScope();
    try {
        MDC.setContextMap(mdcContext);            
        registry.setCurrentObservationScope(currentScope);
        restClient.post().uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("...")
        .build(category))
        .retrieve()
        ...         
    } finally {
        MDC.clear();
        registry.setCurrentObservationScope(oldScope);
    }
}


Thanks a lot. It works. But only with sending requests. The logs still show no values.
But as I understand it, this is due to the fact that the MDC context also needs to be filled out for Tomcat threads?

Looks like I still answered not a question you asked lol. What I actually did is I propagated testRemoteBaggage header from Client to Server, it didn't work before But it looks like you asked something else, sorry for that. I inserted a propagation of MDC Context to FJP/"parallel" threads as you suggested, but let me look closer at what is going on...

@HeorhiUtseuski, yes, with MDC Context propagating to FJP threads, I see this record  --- [autoValuetestRemoteBaggage-] [        ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] [669d34ba6322dd9bc5bc1200fd70c256-c5bc1200fd70c256] o.s.web.client.DefaultRestClient         : Reading to [java.util.List<by.gvu.testtracingrestclient.model.Product>] in the log. If this is what you are looking for, then I'll update my answer with few comments about MDC.

I don’t see a log like the one you provided.
If you have a solution on how to get this, I would be very grateful. This will expand the answer to my question.

Assume you applied to your code my changes I did in respect of MDC Context yesterday. Strange... Let me put my version on github, so that you could see it yourself.

@HeorhiUtseuski. Please check out my PoC.

This works fantastic! I was having trouble propagating the context across to my virtual threads running inside a Custom Executor, this solved the problem really elegantly!
